# How to delete/hide "create new account"

Tags: users

I have 2 roles on my site. I created 2 pages and corresponding links through which each of the roles will register.

I want to prevent users from using the default user registration menu ("create new account") by either deleting it or hiding it. Also i want to prevent users from being able to visit user/register.

Please how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Use [hook_menu_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) to remove default registration page from menu system. Simply `unset($items['user/register']);` and clear menu cache.

Answer (score 2):

I think, there is no need to use hooks or any module for it.

Follow below steps:
1) Go to `Account settings`(admin/config/people/accounts)
2) Under `REGISTRATION AND CANCELLATION` > `Who can register accounts`
3) select `Administrators only`
4) Save configuration
5) Go and check

However, I would like to have feedback from community if I am missing some use-case here where its must to use module/hook.

Comment: I'd say yours is generally the simplest solution, but it sounds like the OP wants to allow anonymous users to register, just not from the user/register page. So in that case, hook_menu_alter is what's needed.

Answer (score 0):

The **easiest** option is to use [Tab Tamer](https://drupal.org/project/tabtamer) to hide any tabs you don't want.

> Tab Tamer is an administration utility that provides easy re-ordering,
>   hiding, and deactivation of tabs and subtabs. You can also rename tab
>   labels.

Then use [`hook_menu_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) to either disable the path, or redirect any requests to another page.

Comment: If he'll disable path via hook, why would he need a Tab Tamer at all? As far as I know tab would disappear anyway if path is removed.

Comment: You are completely correct.  I totally spaced on that! Thanks for pointing it out :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can add path alias in Pathauto (admin/config/search/path/add) ;)

```
Existing system path: any/page
Path alias: user/register
```

This is simplest solution, but has one disadvantage: the url in the browser is still user/register despite the fact that user is on other page.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Configuration** menu and **account setting**,

You can find **Who can register accounts?** 

You select administator only..
That's all..